# How to install unsupported apps in old iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2)

Tags: iphone, ios, apple-store

I've just recovered an old iPhone 4 with iOS 7.1.2 but it is almost unusable because pretty much every app that I need to install says it is unsupported.

How to give life to this phone installing unsupported apps in old iPhone 4 (iOS 7.1.2)?

Comment: iOS 7 is now ancient history. Most apps on the App Store have dropped support for iOS 7. Is there anything specific that you are looking to do with this phone?

Comment: I agree with @NimeshNeema - you'd be better off explicitly listing the functionality you're wanting, but evenso your options, if any, will be very limited. If you're wanting to install specific apps, then this is possible so long as you happen to have backups of the earlier versions of those apps that were compatible with iOS 7.1.2, and you have access to a computer running a version of iTunes that supported installing apps. If this is the case and you have a backup etc, then let us know and we can explain the process for you.

Comment: If you want to do anything fun with it your going to have to jail break it.

Comment: @DanRan, what would jail break allow, in this case?

Comment: @Rodriguez I wish I could answer that as well.

Comment: Maybe an expert has some good answers for that. I would like to know also. Especially if it’s still even possible on that old phone. All underlying aspects would be good to know.

Comment: @Rodriguez see above comment

Comment: @Rodriguez I’ve never done it before. So I’d be interested in what it would allow and if it could really save that phone and allow good apps to work well on it until you could possibly get an upgrade. If an upgrade is possible. Maybe experts have answers.